# A simple problem with definite integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

There is a problem:

A linear function $f(x)$ satisfies that
$\int_{0}^{a}(x^2+x+b)f(x)dx=af(a)$ For all real number $x$.
Find the value of ${a}\times{b}$ (where $a<0$)

I tried differentiate both side by $a$ and compared the coefficients but goes wrong. I cannot find another way. Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: since $f$ is linear, have you tried replacing it's expression by $a \mapsto \lambda a$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and do the computations ? And i suppose you meant "For all real number $a$" instead of $x$, right ?

Comment: It seems to me that the left hand side is a quartic function of $a$ and the right hand side is a quadratic function. This should imply that $f$ is constant. But then the left hand side is cubic and the right hand side is linear, so $f$ is zero.

Comment: @Zag No I haven't tried. And there are no typos in the problem. This is a question my younger brother brought from school, and I also doubt that this question was given incorrectly.

Comment: @HaydnGwyn, I also thought that f(x) should be a constant function, but I am confused because the problem assumes that f(x) is a linear function.

Comment: The phrase "For all real number $x$" doesn't make sense, since the variable $x$ only appears in the integral sign. It doesn't make sens to quantify it... Whereas $a$ is not defined. And if you want to go to the bottom of it, it is quite incorrect to state that $f(x)$ is a function, especially at the level that this problem is supposedly given.

Comment: @Zag You're right. I think the person who wrote this question made a mistake. I'll have to ask him about his intentions.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with:
$$\int_{0}^{a}(x^2+x+b)f(x)dx-af(a)=0$$

Since $f(x)$ is a linear function, Let, for some number $k$, $f(x)=kx$, In fact, you may try $f(x)=kx+d$ also, but for simplicity I assumed $d=0$. I assume the steps would be the same, but the result may differ. Now using $f(x)=kx$, we have:

$$\int _0^a\left(x^2+x+b\right)kxdx-ka^2=k\left(\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{ba^2}{2}\right)-ka^2=0$$

Divide by $k$, where k is not zero to get:

$$\left(\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{a^3}{3}+\frac{ba^2}{2}\right)-a^2=0$$

Separate $ba$ to the left to get:

$$\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{a^3}{3}-a^2=-\frac{ba^2}{2}$$

$$ba=(\frac{-2}{a})(\frac{a^4}{4}+\frac{a^3}{3}-a^2)$$

Comment: I've never thought of it that way, but looking at it like this, the value changes depending on 'a'. Thanks I figured it out